# Need help with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

i'm Russian so sorry for my English. My Russian friends from forum.ubuntu.ru can't help me.

I need to route all connections to my IP to kvm virtual mashine

With iptables-restore:

```
*filter
-N drop-and-log-it
-A drop-and-log-it -j LOG
-A drop-and-log-it -j REJECT
# allow all connections on loopback
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.117 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 90 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.177:80
COMMIT
```

192.168.122.177:80 - works as need
192.168.0.117:90 - nothing

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:60:6e:69:6d:07  
          inet addr:192.168.0.117  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a60:6eff:fe69:6d07/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:79261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8415836 (8.4 MB)  TX bytes:2855090 (2.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2444805 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:2444805 (2.4 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:ee:98:ab  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15149 (15.1 KB)  TX bytes:13225 (13.2 KB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:ee:98:ab  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:feee:98ab/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:17039 (17.0 KB)  TX bytes:104538 (104.5 KB)
```

iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 14 10:23:01 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [62511:4175306]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8701:2000024]
:drop-and-log-it - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A drop-and-log-it -j LOG
-A drop-and-log-it -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 14 10:23:01 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 14 10:23:01 2015
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [65469:4858827]
:INPUT ACCEPT [62843:4204332]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8716:2001632]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8812:2007892]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 14 10:23:01 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 14 10:23:01 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5323:998794]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2710:348676]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1095:89324]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1095:89324]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.117/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 90 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.177:80
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 14 10:23:01 2015
```

ip route show

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.117  metric 1 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
```

Comment: Forwarding is enabled, right? `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` should be 1.

Comment: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: From forum.ubuntu.ru :
filter: FORWARD Need allowed rules to virtual host. Default value is DROP.
How can i apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

The first thing to do is do enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o virbr0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then rdr rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.117 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 90 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.177:80
```